# What state my app will enter into when device receiving alerts (alert view) from other apps (e.g. calendar)

Tags: ios

While the user is playing with my app, there is a calendar alert (alert view) pop up. The user will need to dismiss the calendar alert to back to my app. Before he doing so, what kind of state my app will be running, or put in another way, what kind of event my app will receive so to know that the app is "interrupted" by another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `applicationWillResignActive:`. From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method is called to let your application know that it is about to
>   move from the active to inactive state. This can occur for certain
>   types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or
>   SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the
>   transition to the background state. An application in the inactive
>   state continues to run but does not dispatch incoming events to
>   responders.